# Google Account Sync Error

Tags: sync

I have been looking through all kinds of forums.  But have not yet found a fix. am trying everything but dont want to do a factory reset. I have a samsung galaxy core prime. its about 4 months old and everything has been updated regularly.  I am not sure of the cause of this it it may have been when i accidnetally unchecked the sync button in the menu with wifi, airplane mode etc.  i re-clicked the box and thought nothing of it.otherwise maybe it was when i changed the password of a gmail account/ I cant think of anything else i did.  i dont mess with the settings much.

Basically a few days ago I noticed I wasnt getting gmail notifications.  So i tried to open the gmail app.   Nothing loaded, just a white screen.  At first other gmail accounts I use wouldload but one wouldnt.  Eventually nothing at all would load.  This coincided with play stre not opening, I just get a white screen just like with gmail.  There is the spinning wheel showing that its trying to open but nothing happens.  Also I can not load any of my google sheets docs either.

I ahve tried turing data on and off, airplane mode, clearing cache for all of the google apps.  I eventually tried to delete my google account.  then i added the account again but it wont sync.  it just says syncing and it never finishes the job.

I tried rolling back my google play store to the factory version, did not solve the problem.

As of right now none of these apps will load for any of my google accounts.  even the ones that are listed as synced. some times there is an error message that says experienceing sync errors and check back shortly.

when i currently click gmail its as if i am using it for the first time.  i try to set up email and add an address but the 'next' button does nothing when i click it.  so its as if i have no gmail accounts added but i cant add any.

I would like to delete the gmail app and start again but play store isnt working so not sure if i can. also the fact that all google apps are affected leads me to believe its not a gmail issue but a google account issue.  I guess i could delete all google accounts and try to start fresh? Any other ideas?

I am a bit afraid of losing data or some how screwing up this worse if i delete all my google accounts.  before when i tried to delete the google account that mhy phone is mainly synced with for all the apps it told me i cant because all theother apps are using that account. i cancelled the deletion after reading this warning but it seems to have been deleted anyway.  i re-added the account and it said it was successfull but it wont sync.

does anyone know anything that i can try. thanks , i appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1):

i just managed to get it to work by force shut down of gmail play store and play services. and deleted all app data and cleared the caches for all of these apps and restarted the phone and then i tried to oppen google play and seuddlenlly it asked me to sign in with a new google accoun and suddenly everything was fixed.  been banging my head against the wall all day wwith this.